# AWS EC2 127error on GitHub Actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, github-actions

I am trying to use GitHub Actions with ec2 on my node project and the things are working fine node, npm etc on server but when this action hits on GitHub its keep showing npm command not found but on server I can use npm

```
Run npm i
/home/ec2-user/actions-runner/_work/_temp/4834eb75-d660-4153-8295-0150ec5c725b.sh: line 1: npm: command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

This is the output on linux

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-00-00-225 ~]$ which npm
~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.1/bin/npm
[ec2-user@ip-172-00-00-225 ~]$ which node
~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.1/bin/node
```

.workflow

```
name:  Ci/Cd Pipeline 

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ] 

jobs:
  build:    
    runs-on: self-hosted
    
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]
    
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - run: npm i 
    - run: sudo pm2 kill -a
    - run: sudo pm2 start index.js
```

Comment: Please include your relevant workflow in your question. Are you using is as a self-hosted runner with `npm` preinstalled on it?

Comment: @Azeem I have added a file of workflow

Comment: See [`run_script_step`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/customizing-the-containers-used-by-jobs#run_script_step) and `prependPath`.